# Java get time at specified intervals, tenth of second, 100th of a second

Tags: java, multithreading

Hello I'm trying to figure out a way in which my main thread return's a value every 1/10th or 1/n second for example...

```
public class MainGameLoop {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
     //Run Game Logic
     //every 1/10th second update skeletal animation
     //ever 1/30th second update texture animation
    }
}
```

I've been experimenting with seperate threads like this

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {

public void run() {
     try{
    Thread.sleep(500)
    System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
    catch(Exectpion e) {

   }
}
```

but the sleep effects my main thread's  thread. If I sleep for 10 seconds, my mainthread sleeps for 10 seconds.

I've tried

```
Runnable z = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
   try {
   Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

             System.out.println("hi"); 
        }
     };


     ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
     executor.submit(z);
    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
     //Run Game logic
    }
}
```

This only runs once at initialization and delay's the "hi" after the specified sleep amount, alternatively this

```
Runnable z = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
   try {
   Thread.sleep(100000);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

             System.out.println("hi"); 
        }
     };


     ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
     //Run Game logic
      executor.submit(z);
    }
}
```

prints out "hi" as fast as the main thread can refresh.

Comment: Have you looked into `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`? Just be aware that this entire approach has issues for a game loop if the CPU can't keep up with your updates.

Comment: ooh yea, that works great.  I used http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/scheduledthreadpoolexecutor/java-util-concurrent-scheduledthreadpoolexecutor-example/  and used time increments of milliseconds

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Comment: My display loop is controlled by LWJGL underneath and I can sync it to a specified refresh rate, 0-N fps.  Is this what you mean by if the game loop cannot keep up with with the updates?. I just realized what you said.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class TimerDemo extends TimerTask
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TimerTask tasknew = new TimerDemo();
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tasknew, 0, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("once every 1000 ms");
    }
}
```

All of the tasks run on the same thread. In the above example if `run()` takes longer than 1000 ms to execute, the next scheduled execution will be delayed. See the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)) for more details. If you want multiple threads use a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) instead.